# Unable to create two-dimensional array from a dynamic string

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach

I am trying to load a dynamic string to an existing empty array(to create an array of array). The dynamic string looks like this (one, two, or more arrays of number separated by comma)

```
$str = "[52,18,140,41,56],[54,18,145,43,58]";
```

and loading it to an empty array in

```
$arr = explode(',', $str);
```

It looks like I am loading the data to array as the `print_r($arr);` is printing

```
Array ( 
    [0] => [52 
    [1] => 18 
    [2] => 140 
    [3] => 41 
    [4] => 56] 
    [5] => [54 
    [6] => 18 
    [7] => 145 
    [8] => 43 
    [9] => 58] 
)
```

but when I try to access them through `foreach ($arr as list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e)` I am not getting any thing

```
$arr = [];
$str = "[52,18,140,41,56],[54,18,145,43,58]";
$arr = explode(',', $str);

print_r($arr);

echo '<table style="width:40%">';
foreach ($arr as list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e)) {
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<th>'.$a.'</th>';
     echo '<th>'.$b.'</th>';
     echo '<th>'.$c.'</th>';
     echo '<th>'.$d.'</th>';
     echo '<th>'.$e.'</th>';
     echo '</tr>';  
}
echo '</table>';
```

Why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: You should use variable in second part of `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_split()` instead that can split string by regex. Using it `[` & `]` doesn't add to array.

```
$arr = preg_split("/[\[\],]+/", $str);
foreach ($arr as $item){
    if (!empty($item))
        // do something
}
```

So your code changed to

```
$str = "[52,18,140,41,56],[54,18,145,43,58]";
$arr = preg_split("/[\[\],]+/", $str);

echo '<table style="width:40%"><tr>';
foreach ($arr as $item){
    if (!empty($item))
        echo "<th>{$item}</th>";
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/oH9V8)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$str = "[52,18,140,41,56],[54,18,145,43,58]";
$arr = explode('],[', $str);

echo '<table style="width:40%">';
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $item = trim($item,'[]');
    list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) = explode(',', $item);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>'.$a.'</th>';
    echo '<th>'.$b.'</th>';
    echo '<th>'.$c.'</th>';
    echo '<th>'.$d.'</th>';
    echo '<th>'.$e.'</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Which outputs:

```
<table style="width:40%">
    <tr>
        <th>52</th><th>18</th><th>140</th><th>41</th><th>56</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>54</th><th>18</th><th>145</th><th>43</th><th>58</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Bary thanks for reply this is loading the array properly but still is not echoing any table and td on page

Comment: I tested this code on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and I see "<table style="width:40%"><tr><th>52</th><th>18</th><th>140</th><th>41</th><th>56</th></tr><tr><th>54</th><th>18</th><th>145</th><th>43</th><th>58</th></tr></table>" as the output